# How to line up the bottoms of image and text in a bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a reasonably basic bootstrap navbar as seen in code below.

The pieces I care about here are the logo `unified_brand.png` and the `Contact` link.  I would like to somehow line up the bottoms of the brand image and Contact text link.

Is it possible to do it programmatically?  I've been messing pixels with the padding and margins and it did the trick but it feels like there should be a better answer?

```css
.navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#navBarMain {
    border-top: 5px solid #ff5c39;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navBarMain">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img style="" src="~/images/unified_brand.png" alt="Company Logo">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Small trick, works like charm, place an inline-block before the element you want to align with. For this to work, the parent tag must have a define height.

```
#navBarMain {
    border-top: 5px solid #ff5c39;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.small-trick{
  width: 0 ;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;;
}

.navbar-header{
  height: 37pt;
}
 .navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
}



<nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navBarMain">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="small-trick" ></div>
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img style="" src="~/images/unified_brand.png" alt="Company Logo">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```